# Where can I look up a companies Herfindahl index?

Tags: data-request, self-study, industrial-organisation

Where can I find Herfindahl indexes on companies (current or past)? Are there any published lists put out by a research institution?

Comment: Also I don't have enough karma to add the correct tags to this question.

Answer (score 1):

HHI index cannot by definition be *on companies*. It is the squared sum of market shares of all the companies in a country. So, if you are looking for companies' market shares, you should look at each country individually.

But if you want HHI index *on countries* (which is a correct way of framing the question) then you can use this WorldBank data: https://tcdata360.worldbank.org/indicators/hh.mkt